# Error "Could not connect to MySQL with the given password" while reinstalling MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've tried to reinstall MySQL Server and Workbench and when I got to the part where I was supposed to set up the username and password, I was asked to insert a password.
[image]

Comment: use the  same password as in tghe first installation.

Comment: @nbk it worked:)) But what would I have done if I didn't remember the password. Is there a way to fix this issue in that case?

Comment: Then you have to change the password before hand.