# Cannot reinstall MySql "Could not connect to MySql with the given password" on Windows. Forgot root password

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am learning Spring Batch. I followed the instructions to install MySQL Shell 8.0.26 and also the Workbench 8.0 on Windows 11.

However I get

```
MySQL  JS > alter user 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password by 'password';
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
 MySQL  JS > show schemas;
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
 MySQL  JS > show databases;
```

So I tried to uninstall and reinstall MySql.
When I run the installer,

[image: mysql error message]

I have forgotten the root password. What should I do?

In this [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60712349/error-could-not-connect-to-mysql-with-the-given-password-while-reinstalling-my) SO question the person remembered the password.

I did an internet search and tried to follow the steps here

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>.\\mysqld --init-file=C:\\Documents\\mysql-init.txt
2021-11-15T00:37:15.052478Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.26) starting as process 5260
2021-11-15T00:37:15.054496Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2021-11-15T00:37:15.054535Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2021-11-15T00:37:15.054651Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\' (OS errno: 2 - No such file or directory)
2021-11-15T00:37:15.056382Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-11-15T00:37:15.056496Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.26)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this article and it says that one must manually delete the following folders. Merely Uninstalling from Windows Control Panel is not enough.

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL

C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL

C:\ProgramData\MySQL
```

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_programs/how-to-completely-uninstall-mysql/e90e1344-7b90-4319-8b2f-77b271ae66ed

I followed the steps and when I ran the installer again, it asked for a new root password!